# Adding and removing to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

I wasn't sure how to word this, because I don't actually know what exactly causes this bug. I'm trying to put together a simple Asteroids knockoff.

When the player shoots, a new object (Bullet) is created using `array.push(...)`. Once this bullet goes beyond the canvas (out of bounds), it is deleted using `array.splice(...);`

The problem is that the bullets are moving in unpredictable ways. I don't know how to word it so here's the full code (working, including html/css): https://pastebin.com/tKiSnDzX
Hold spacebar for a few seconds (to shoot) and you'll see the issue clearly. You can also use A/D to turn and W to go forward.

Here's what I think is happening. The code runs fine as long as there is only one bullet on the screen (in the array). This means that either the incorrect element is being deleted or the values that go into the constructor of the object are messed up somewhere along the way.

Exhibit A (bullet constructor and its methods):

```
function Bullet(x,y,rot,vel) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.rot = rot;
    this.vel = (vel+5);

    this.move = function() {
        this.x += this.vel*Math.cos(this.rot-Math.PI/2);
        this.y += this.vel*Math.sin(this.rot-Math.PI/2);
    }

    this.draw = function() {
        engine.circle(this.x, this.y, 4, "black");

        var c = engine.canvas.getContext('2d');
        c.translate(this.x, this.y);
        c.rotate(this.rot);
        c.beginPath();
        c.strokeStyle="#00FF00";
        c.strokeRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
        c.closePath();
        c.stroke();
    }
}
```

Exhibit B (function that creates/deletes the bullets):

```
shoot: function() {
            if(engine.keyDown.sp == true) {
                if(this.fire > 20) {
                    engine.bullets.unshift(new Bullet(this.x, this.y, this.rot, this.velocity));
                    this.fire = 0;
                } else {
                    this.fire++
                }
            }
            for(i = 0; i < engine.bullets.length; i++) {
                engine.bullets[i].move();
                engine.bullets[i].draw();
                if(engine.bullets[i].x > engine.canvas.width+5 || engine.bullets[i].x < -5 
                || engine.bullets[i].y > engine.canvas.height+5  || engine.bullets[i].y < -5) {
                    console.log('bullet gone, '+i);
                    engine.bullets.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

the array is declared like so: `bullets: []`

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: In the `for` loop, every time the array gets shortened, one needs to take care of the array's length. Thus you might think about assigning `bullets.length` to a variable, using this variable in the loop's condition and then decrementing this variable every time you remove a bullet item from it's array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as it turns out, that wasn't the problem. I tried putting `context.save();` and `context.restore();` to where the translation/rotation happens for the bullets. Now there are no issues

Comment: @JanProcházka You should put that as an answer and mark it as correct - especially if you know why that was the correct answer and can explain it!

Comment: Never use `splice` in forward `for` loop. When `i`-th element is removed by `splice`, all elements from `i+1` to the last are shifted left and their indexes are changed respectively. That's why you get unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was translating the context in which all the bullets are, each time a new bullet was created. This meant that each bullet would be moved by x and y away from the previous one. It made it seem like the bullets were being created where they weren't supposed to be. The "unpredictability" was caused by the fact that the bullet takes on the player's rotation, so whenever a new bullet was created, it's rotation was increased by however much the player rotated before the new bullet was fired, on top of the previous bullet's rotation.

Putting `context.save();` before the translation/rotation of the bullet's hitbox and `context.restore();` after it perfectly solved the issue:

```
Bullet.draw = function() {
    engine.circle(this.x, this.y, 4, "black");
    if(hitbox == true) {
        var c = engine.canvas.getContext('2d');
        c.save();
        c.translate(this.x, this.y);
        //c.rotate(this.rot);
        c.beginPath();
        c.strokeStyle="#00FF00";
        c.strokeRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
        c.closePath();
        c.stroke();
        c.restore();
    }
}
```

Someone else mentioned that I was using `array.splice();` in a for loop. This made it so that when a bullet (i) is deleted, the bullet right after (i+1) is moved one index back (i). So that bullet was essentially skipped over.

I could notice this sometimes when looking at the bullets while one was deleted- They "jumped" ahead.

The solution was to put `i -= 1` after `bullets.splice(i, 1);`. This makes the next iteration of the loop go one index back, solving the occassional stuttering of the bullets:

```
shoot: function() {
        if(engine.keyDown.sp == true) {
            if(this.fire > 5) {
                engine.bullets.unshift(new Bullet(this.x, this.y, this.rot, this.velocity));
                this.fire = 0;
            }
        }
        if(this.fire<=5) {
            this.fire++
        }
        for(i = 0; i < engine.bullets.length; i++) {
            engine.bullets[i].move();
            engine.bullets[i].draw();
            if(engine.bullets[i].x > engine.canvas.width+5 || engine.bullets[i].x < -5 
            || engine.bullets[i].y > engine.canvas.height+5  || engine.bullets[i].y < -5) {
                engine.bullets.splice(i, 1);
                i-=1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about just tag any bullets that need to die as you come across them in your loop with something like `engine.bullets[i].dead = true;`  Then, at the end outside the loop, filter out the dead bullets with `engine.bullets = engine.bullets.filter(b => !b.dead);`

Answer (score 0):

You're using splice inside a for loop. When you remove element index 1, then element index 2 becomes index 1, and element index 3 becomes index 2. But your *i* variable is already 1, so the next iteration of the loop goes to the new index 2. But the new index 2 is the original index 3, and the original index 2 is skipped. You might be better served by a linked list:

```
var bulletList = null;
function bullet(){
  this.next = bulletList;//if there was a list, record that
  if (this.next)//and set that one to point back to this
   this.next.prev = this;
  bulletList = this;//place new bullet at start of list
  this.previous = null;

  this.draw = function(){
    //do stuff here
    this.next && this.next.draw();//call next item in the list, if any
    if (shouldIBeRemoved){//placeholder, obviously
      if (this.next && this.prev){//remove from middle of list
        this.prev.next = this.next;
        this.next.prev = this.prev;
      }
      else if (this.next && !this.prev){//remove from beginning of list
        bulletList = this.next;
        this.next.prev = null;
      }
      else if (this.prev && !this.next){//remove from end of list
        this.prev.next = null;
      }
      else if (!this.prev && !this.next){//remove only item in list
        bulletList = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then to draw every bullet, simply call:

```
if (bulletList)
  bulletList.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually don't need to go that far. I simply just do this `i-=1` after `bullets.splice(i, 1);`. This sets the index of the for loop 1 back and solves a minor bug (it was working without it)